# Need to change appearance of LWC based on a record's field

Tags: lightning-web-components, customsetting, custom-metadata

How to store an information that let users to change the LWC's appearance dynamically?

The user can define rules like:

- If that field's value is **"X"**, appearance should be **"A"** and/or **"Y" -> "B"** (it can be configurable to **"Y" -> "A"**, **"X" -> "B"** too)

Custom Settings or Custom Metadata come to my mind but is there any other way to achieve this functionality in LWC?

Comment: Custom settings or metadata sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create that field as a **picklist** with different *Label & API Name*
  Eg : Country:  **IN** -> INDIA , **US** -> United States, etc.

  If the picklist field does not achieve your requirement then go with
  Custom settings or metadata type.
- Better to Use the **Custom Metadata Type** then we can deploy our records / Configurations to production easily.
  [https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_changesets.htm&type=5][1]